# Python; how to replace string pattern and save to a file, rename the file by string variable from folder name to the filename?

Tags: python, string, filenames

I have own folder for each product in the filesystem;

```
/PRODUCTS/PRODUCT_XXX

/PRODUCT_001
/PRODUCT_002
/PRODUCT_003
/PRODUCT_004
/PRODUCT_005
...
/PRODUCT_999
```

Each folder have PRODUCT_XXX.html file and picture and data of the product...

I would not wan't to remake all the PRODUCT_XXX.html files,

if I would like to change the layout of the html...

I would like to have one PRODUCT_XXX.html file at the root folder,

```
/PRODUCTS/PRODUCT_XXX.html
```

then copy it to all of the product number folders,
replacing just the pattern  XXX -->  the product number from the FOLDER NAME

```
prodnum = "555"    #  Actually,  would need to read the Product Number from the OS
                   folder name..
               #  But will do that later,  after I get this on the below working...

f1 = open('PRODUCT_XXX.html', 'r')
f2 = open('/PRODUCT_%D/PRODUCT_%D.html', prodnum, 'w'  )
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('PRODUCT_XXX', 'PRODUCT_%D', prodnum))
                # (then later could do also other things here..)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

I was trying  %D,  %s  ...    but  was not able to get save the PRODUCT_555.html file
How to save file by string variable name?  Tried to google some example, but those seems hard to find..

Comment: Note that `%d` is not going to give you `'001'` for 1, it's going to give you `'1'` (and `%D` isn't going to give you anything; I don't know where you even got that from). You need `%03d` to page with 0s up to width 3. Or, if you switch to `str.format` as the answers suggest, `{0:03}` or `{0:03d}`, not just `{0}`.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `%`, e.g.

```
f2.write(line.replace('PRODUCT_XXX', 'PRODUCT_%d' % prodnum)) # note lowercase d
```

But this would be clearer and less error-prone using `str.format`:

```
f2.write(line.replace('PRODUCT_XXX', 'PRODUCT_{0}'.format(prodnum)))
```

Comment: The first one won't work; it'll just raise a `ValueError` because there is no format character `'D'`. But that's the OP's mistake, not yours, and it's a perfect illustration of your very next sentence about `str.format` being clearer and less error-prone…

Comment: @abarnert fixed, thank you; I never normally use `%`, although I should still have tested it!

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
f2 = open('/PRODUCT_{0}/PRODUCT_{0}.html'.format(prodnum), 'w')
```

Comment: import shutil

file_read = open("index_numbers.txt", 'r')

def do_the_thing(indexnum):
   print(indexnum)
   file1 = open("fileXXX.html", 'r')
   file2 = open("file{0}.html".format(indexnum), 'wb')
   for line in file1:
    file2.write(line.replace('XXX', '%s' % indexnum))   
   file1.close()
   file2.close()


   
line_from_file = file_read.readline()
for line_from_file in file_read:
  print(line_from_file) 
  line_from_file = line_from_file[0:-1]
  indexnum = line_from_file
  
   shutil.copy2('fileXXX.html', 'file{0}.html'.format(indexnum))
  
  do_the_thing(indexnum)
file_read.close()

Answer (score 0):

If I have a index_numbers.txt,   with numbers   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...  1000  one number at one line;

```
  import shutil
  file_read = open("index_numbers.txt", 'r')


  def do_the_thing(indexnum):
     print(indexnum)
     file1 = open("fileXXX.html", 'r')
     file2 = open("file{0}.html".format(indexnum), 'wb')

     for line in file1:
        file2.write(line.replace('XXX', '%s' % indexnum))   

     file1.close()
     file2.close()


  line_from_file = file_read.readline()

     for line_from_file in file_read:
       print(line_from_file) 
       line_from_file = line_from_file[0:-1]
       indexnum = line_from_file

       shutil.copy2('fileXXX.html', 'file{0}.html'.format(indexnum))

       do_the_thing(indexnum)

   file_read.close()
```

Something like that would do the thing?
But how to modify this script,  if one would like to replace more text fields in file;

```
   -  replace the XXX with the index number
   -  replace the YYY with Product short name
   -  replace the ZZZ with Product long name
   -  ...
```